# HTML & CSS Video Style

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I was wondering how to style the buttons and the whole element of an HTML Video with CSS. I would like to know the steps that need to be taken to complete these actions.

```
<video class="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: @BrendanOggeri check here http://mrbool.com/how-to-style-the-html-5-video-element-with-javascript-and-css/27683

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) for custom html5 video player.

> Video.js is pretty easy to set up. It can take a matter of seconds to
>   get the player up and working on your web page.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you may style the buttons and the controls of the video tag, but you can at least apply some styles for the whole video itself, such as:

```
video {
   border: 5px groove darkblue;
   padding: 30px;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
}
```

I tried to play with the controls' styles a bit, but got no results.

```
[controls] {
    background: red;
    color: red;
}

::controls, ::-controls, ::-webkit-controls {
    background: red;
    color: red;
}
```

<strike>*<sup>(Yes, I know what I tried was dumb, but at least I tried!)</sup>*</strike>

If you are okay with using JavaScript to do that, you might want to look at [VIDEO.JS](http://www.videojs.com/) or at [this article](http://mrbool.com/how-to-style-the-html-5-video-element-with-javascript-and-css/27683) from MrBool where everything is done manually.

Answer (score 2):

try setting an id .For example:

```
<video class="video" id="video-style" width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

CSS:
#video-style{
border:2px solid blue;
padding:5px;
/**Or add your own style**/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can style it using element selector;

```
video {
border: 5px solid red;
/*Your CSS here for styling*/
}
```

For advance styling & skinning styling look in to [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/).

Also a good read [Build a custom HTML5 video player](http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-custom-html5-video-player-9134473).